# Project point coordinate on Z plane

Tags: objective-c, language-agnostic, geometry, projection

I've been struggling with this (apparently simple) problem :

- I have a point (actually a mouse point, that can catch and move vertices in a 2D geometry) which has some coordinates, let's say x and y on plane z = 0.
- I want to be able to zoom / unzoom in my geometry by moving my 2D plane to a specific Z.
- To be able to drag my geometry points with the mouse (point (x, y)), the program need to receive the vertices coordinates at z = 0., even if the plane is at z = -2. for example.

I searched a lot about projection and tried to follow these :

- http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial12/tutorial12.html
- http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/lens/

But I can't manage to get what I want...

Here is my code (in Obj-C) but it's language agnostic :

```
    double width = context.bounds.size.width;
    double height = context.bounds.size.height;

    double alpha = 2. * atan((height / 2.) / fabs(self.inputZ));

    projectedX = self.inputX / (self.inputZ * tan(alpha / 2.));
    projectedY = self.inputY / (self.inputZ * tan(alpha / 2.));
```

I would appreciate any advice on this simple problem ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at my answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881026/1219956). there is a glu function that is ported that can project points to screen coordinates. If you are not using GLK functions you can just edit it to whatever you are using, otherwise import glkit to use their math functions so you can use it as is.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on a Quartz Composer plugin, and I'd like to avoid importing other libraries, because of the "noodling" way of plugging functions in QC. What I need is the actual formula to find these points...

Comment: ah i see, maybe you can decipher the function in that answer to help you with what you need. but if you arent using a proper 3d environment with a projection/model matrix then this way wont work i guess.